# rhc port-forward not working for collaborated app

Tags: openshift, portforwarding, collaboration, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to use the "rhc port-forward " command for an app that my friend has made me a collaborator on. The app appears with my other apps when I do "rhc apps" and the gear is not off or in idle. Does anyone know what is wrong or if it is an openshift bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since their application is in another namespace, make sure that you are using the -n or --namespace flag when running rhc port-forward

```
Usage: rhc port-forward <application>

Forward remote ports to the workstation


Options
  -n, --namespace NAME      Name of a domain
  -g, --gear ID             Gear ID you are port forwarding to (optional)
  -a, --app NAME            Name of an application
```